# FB.ui feed. How do I get the current tab URL?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code for a share button in my app

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: '',
        picture: 'icon.png',
        name: '',
        caption: '',
        description: ''
});
```

However this app will be installed on multiple facebook tabs. How do I get the current facebook tab URL so I can insert it into 'link' above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the page can be found in the `signed_request` initially posted to your app. You need to use this.

Comment: I've managed to get the page ID. Is there a way to get the app id?
So I can can populate the URL with sk=app_